# directed graph with two transitive reduction which have diffrent number of edges

Tags: facebook-graph-api, math, graph

Please,
I need  help in finding an example of directed graph with two transitive reduction with different number of edges.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, a transitive reduction of a directed graph is a graph with as few edges as possible that has the same reachability relation as the given graph.

So it is not possible to find two transitive reduction with different number of edges,if there are two,the one with more edges will not be a transitive reduction.

Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) to get more infomation.

Comment: tahnks for your help , but that is not correct , if the graph is acyclic directed graph then there could be two transitive reduction with different number of edges.